# Problems with file upload in chrome-based browser on KDE

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, kde, manjaro

After a recent Manjaro update, I cannot upload any file to any site (such as Gmail) using any chromium-based browser from a folder containing non-Latin characters, while uploading from a folder containing only letters of the English alphabet works fine. At the same time, Firefox uploads any file without problems.

The only difference between browsers is the dialog window used. Chrome uses xdg-desktop-portal-kde and Firefox uses GTK dialog. Is there any way to fix the issue with xdg-desktop-portal-kde or force Chrome to use GTK dialog as a workaround?

Comment: Did you try installing kdialog? sudo pacman -Syyu kdialog

Comment: Yes, it was installed. Dead ssd and new system install solve the problem